# Inbox notification and reputation score is misaligned in mobile web view

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

The inbox notification indicator and reputation score indicator are misaligned in the mobile web view.

> [image: Mobile web view]

Comment: I thought that they were intentionally offset so that you can still see the icon underneath them...

Comment: @Catija when a bug is so well concealed, you think it's [tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: Looks like a CSS error.

Comment: @Arulkumar looks like I beat you to it by 1h20m [over on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362829/achievements-and-inbox-counters-misaligned-in-mobile-web-view) :)

Comment: @Pawel: Was a partial fix rolled out already? I just got a notification that was *less* shifted (but still a bit).

Comment: @pawel it's fixed for me. No more offset.

Comment: @chirlu Fix rolled out, fixed completely? Not so sure. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362829/achievements-and-inbox-counters-misaligned-in-mobile-web-view?noredirect=1#comment554979_362829

Answer (score 8):

Even worse, it throws the entire layout off. This is not how it was yesterday.

[image]

Notice the white space on the right, caused by this offset rep added icon. Someone messed up the css for the top bar.

S7, Samsung browser (chromium). OP is using an LG or Moto phone and looks like Chrome, so it's not just a different rendering issue.

***Update:*** seems to be fixed at 2/5 4:30pm. No more offset icon or white space for me.

Comment: I’ve got the same issue on Firefox Mobile (ESR, Android), so it’s not limited to Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: **Not fixed**. Still partially wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Seems fixed, but only **partially**. It looks fine if you have no more than `+99` rep change, and things are still wrong beyond that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whomever deleted the comments, I hope you realized it was tongue in cheek.