# Bug in mobile view

Tags: bug, mobile-web

I've spotted a bug in the mobile view of the network. It's near the notification box and the achievement tracker (top right corner):

[image: Bug in mobile view]

Those who are used to the mobile view, would be knowing that previously, the "1" or any number would completely hide the notification box, and the "+5" or any such number would completely honest the achievement tracker symbol. Currently these have moved to the right.

Hope that the site developers will look into this.

Comment: Already reported: [Inbox notification and reputation score is misaligned in mobile web view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306538/inbox-notification-and-reputation-score-is-misaligned-in-mobile-web-view)